# Expression for elements greater than x and less than y in python, all in one return statement. No loop. Python

Tags: python, numpy

Return the number of items in the array `A` that are greater than x and less than y. `A` is a 1-D float array and x and y are floats. For example `F6(np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 2.3]), 2, 3)` should return `2`.

```
def F(A,x,y):
     return ________?
```

Only this line can be used. 
In python

Comment: And where are you getting stuck?

Comment: This is sometimes called a "filter" operation (the count afterwards is cosmetic). Assuming `A` is iterable, see both `itertools.ifilter`, and a list comprehension that uses "if".

Comment: How about you show some effort first?

Comment: Well, you forgot to assign the expected answer (from the back of the textbook) to the variable `________`. Fix that, and get rid of the question mark, and you can turn in your homework.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it as a vectorized operation:

```
import numpy as np

def F(A, x, y):
    return np.sum((A > x) & (A < y))
```

Each comparison returns a boolean array. The expression ANDs these two arrays elementwise and sums the result.

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about numpy, but in vanilla python:

```
def F(A, x, y):
    return sum(x < v < y for v in A)
```

This uses the fact that you can count the number of `True`s in a boolean array by summing, since `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`.

Comment: I would take advantage of numpy arrays he's using (loops in C): `sum((A > x) & (A < y))`

Comment: @JBernardo: Wouldn't surprise me if `sum(x < A < y)` worked as well then.

Comment: No, because that uses a logical `and`

Comment: @JBernardo: Sorry, I hadn't seen your comment when I answered. I assume you're using `np.sum` there . Using an iterator to sum a NumPy array would be orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is an option.

```
def F(A,x,y):
    return len([i for i in A if i > x and i < y])
```

Comment: or `sum(bool(i > x and i < y) for i in A )`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Which can be improved further to become my answer. Why convert a `bool` to a `bool`?

Comment: @Eric You're right, `bool()` is redundant here, +1 to your solution.